# Decrypt data only for authorized client

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an asp.net mvc web application  with some customers.

A new customer tells me that its data should be crypted on its client and then sent to server (that will store the data into database).

When the client will request the data, they will be read from db and decrypted on client side.
As is, only he will be able to display the correct data.

I found another post, but i need some samples.

Can i make it with javascript?
How it works? javascript read the private key from a certificate on client machine?

[How could you encrypt user data so only they can decrypt it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695813/how-could-you-encrypt-user-data-so-only-they-can-decrypt-it)

tks

Comment: So was my answer helpful? if so, then please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Public Key Encryption with Javascript:
http://shop-js.sourceforge.net/crypto2.htm

Keep in mind that you can't read local files with javascript alone.  You might need to have a Silverlight app running on the client-side as silverlight can read local files.  Maybe have your login screen done in Silverlight?

http://www.insidercoding.com/post/2008/08/17/Reading-Local-Files-in-Silverlight.aspx